# How can I update the this.state.songs to songsList

Tags: reactjs, state

I cant update the state songs which needs to get values from songsList . How can I update the songs to songsList ? Is it anything to do with the component life cycle ? While running the below code , 'songsList is undefined' error throws up .  const songList is in the render .

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import logo from './components/Logo/box8.png';
    import './App.css';
    import SearchBox from './components/SearchBox/SearchBox';
    import SongCards from './components/SongCards/SongCards';
    import 'tachyons';
    import axios from 'axios';

    class App extends Component {
          state = {
            songs : [],
          searchField: '',
          entries: []
          };



      componentDidMount() {
          axios.get(`https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topalbums/limit=100/json`)
          .then(response => 
            {this.setState({ entries: response.data.feed.entry });

          });
        }

    onSearchChange=(event)=>{
      this.setState({songs : songsList})
        this.setState({searchField : event.target.value})
        const filteredSongs = this.state.songs.filter(song =>{
          return song.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchField.toLowerCase())
        });
     }

       render(){

          const songsList = this.state.entries.map(entries => {
          return (
            <SongCards 
              key={entries.id.label} 
              artist={entries["im:artist"].label}
              image={entries["im:image"][2].label}
              link={entries.id.label}
              price={entries["im:price"].label}
              date={entries["im:releaseDate"].label}
              title={entries.title.label}
            />
          );
        });



        return (
          <div className="App">

            <header className="App-header">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            </header>
            <SearchBox searchChange= {this.onSearchChange}/>
            {songsList}


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: WHATS your exact issue? songsList undefined? How does your this.state.entries looks like? Can you do console log and update the data in question so that it’s easy for us to check

Comment: it is an object containing songs detail
Object
category: {
id: {label: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/album/aravindha-sameth…inal-motion-picture-soundtrack-ep/1436841209?uo=2", 
im:artist: {label: "Thaman S.", attributes: {…}}
im:contentType: {im:contentType: {…}, 
im:image: (3) 
im:itemCount: {label: "4"}
im:name: {label: "Aravindha Sametha (Original Motion Picture Soundtrack) - EP"}
im:price: {label: "₹ 60",
im:releaseDate: {label: "2018-09-20T00:00:00-07:00", 
rights: {label: "℗ 2018 Zee Music Company"}
title: {label: "Aravindha Sametha (Original Motion Picture Soundtrack) "}

Comment: Can you please put this data in your question? Also you didn’t confirm your exact issue

Comment: I cant put this object data in the question due to formatting issue . I want to update the this.state.songs to the output im getting for const songsList .

Comment: I want to get the songs searched in the search field

Answer (score 2):

Appreciate all your responses . I made it finally .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './components/Logo/box8.png';
import './App.css';
import SearchBox from './components/SearchBox/SearchBox';
import Albums from './components/Albums/Albums';
import Scroll from './components/Scroll/Scroll';
import 'tachyons';
import emoji from 'emoji-dictionary';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
      state = {
        show:false,
        songs : [],
      searchField: '',
      };


  componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(`https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topalbums/limit=100/json`)
      .then(response => 
        {this.setState({songs:response.data.feed.entry });
         });
    }

itunesPageLoader=()=>{
  this.setState({show:false})
}

onSearchChange=(event)=>{
    this.setState({searchField : event.target.value})

 }

   render(){

    const filteredSongs = this.state.songs.filter(song =>{
      return 
 song.title.label.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchField.toLowerCase())
    })

 return (

      <div className="App">


        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        </header>
        <SearchBox searchChange= {this.onSearchChange}/>
        <Scroll >
        <Albums songs={filteredSongs}/>
        </Scroll>
        <footer className="pv4 ph3 ph5-m ph6-l red">
            <small className="f6 db tc">© 2018 <b className="ttu">Box8 Inc</b>., All 
     Rights Reserved</small>
            <div className="tc mt3">
               {`Made with  ${emoji.getUnicode("purple_heart")} by Renjith`}
            </div>
        </footer>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You are actually assigning songsList to songs using setState but the songsList doesn’t exist in onSearchChange. To push searched value to an array you need to push event.target.value to songs array

Try with below corrected code

```
  onSearchChange=(event)=>{
       this.setState(prevState => ({songs : [...prevState.songs, event.target.value]}));
        this.setState({searchField : event.target.value})
         const filteredSongs = this.state.songs.filter(song =>{
         return song.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchField.toLowerCase())
        });
     }
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick response.I want all the objects inside the state.songs before getting into onsearchchange

Comment: Can anyone advise me on a better Header text animation in a react javascript app ? I want to add a cool Header text for my app .

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that `this.state.entries` is an `Object`.
If this is true, then yo can't perform `.map` on it as `.map` is an `Array` method.

You can however use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of `[key,value]` pairs of `this.state.entries`.

```
Object.entries(this.state.entries).map(([key,value]) => ...)
```

Simple running example:

```js
const object1 = { foo: 'this is foo', baz: "this is baz" };
Object.entries(object1).map(([key,value]) => console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${value}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

So i will do something like this:

```
const IN_PROGRESS = 'IN_PROGRESS';
const SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    songs : null,
    entries: null,
    status: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
     this.setState({status: IN_PROGRESS});

     axios.get(`https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topalbums/limit=100/json`)
      .then({data} => {
        const songs = data.feed.entry;

        this.setState({entries: songs});
        this.setState({songs});
        this.setState({status: SUCCESS});
      });
    }

  onSearchChange = ({target}) => {
    const {value} = target;

    const songs = this.state.entires.filter(song => 
      song.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    });

    this.setState({songs});
  }

  render() {
    const {status, songs} = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        </header>

        <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>

        {
           status === IN_PROGRESS && 
            (/* you can insert here some kind of loader which indicates that data is loading*/)
        }

        {
           status === SUCCESS && songs.map(entry => {
             const {
               id, ['im:artist']: artist, ['im:image']: image,
               ['im:price']: price, ['im:releaseDate']: date, title
             } = entry;

             return (
               <SongCard
                 key={id.label} 
                 artist={artist.label}
                 image={image[2].label}
                 link={id.label}
                 price={price.label}
                 date={date.label}
                 title={entry.title.label}
               />
             )
           }
        }

        {
           //Here you can display error message if status === FAILURE
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

1. When component did mount, I set status into IN_PROGRESS (if you want some kind of loader to show), and data are beeing fetched - `axios.get` is asynchronous so remember that when data is fetching then render method is already triggered. When data is loaded then in state I hold two variables, `entries` which holds unfiltered list of songs, and `songs` which holds filteres songs.
2. When `search` is triggered then I filter `entires` by searched phrase and set into state this filtered array.
3. Component renders `songCards` mapping by filtered `songs`